# How to enable / disable my app that is being managed from theme customization section shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am trying to enable/disable my app using APIs but could not find any API or any other way to do it automatically from my app.

[image]

Is there any way to enable / disable app automatically ?

Comment: You can't do the same, from API end. it add and store data into theme JSON files regarding on/off for section and app block settings.

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer after some R & D

[image]

As per the above screenshot, we may edit "settings_data.json" file to keep the status disable/enable.

Comment: Yes, you need to asset API with read_theme, and write_theme scopes to edit and update particular files using code logic.